# jUnit how to use @Test(expected=...)

Tags: java, junit

I have this method:

```
public String getNum(int x) throws Exception
{
    if(x == 0) {
         throws new Exception("x cannot be 0");
    }
    ...
}
```

now in my JUnit test, I try this

```
@Test(expected=Exception.class)
public void testNum() {
     String x = getNum(0);
}
```

But Eclipse still wants to me to either add a throws declaration or surround with try catch for `String x = getNum(0);`. What did I do wrong? This test should pass since I expected an Exception when I pass in 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `throws` clause to the declaration of `testNum`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am such as noob

Comment: Everybody is blind at times. With > 2k points here you cannot really be a noob.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `throws` declaration which Java compiler requires for checked exceptions. In your case it is nothing more than declaration :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am such as noob